# Issue with the scrolling behaviour of the bottom sheet

Tags: reactjs, react-native, bottom-sheet

I was using this library "react-native-simple-bottom-sheet". I have some issues with the scrolling behaviour. I'm rendering this bottom sheet on touch of the text "Truminds" present in the toolbar section of the home screen. The issue is that when i am trying to scroll through the bottom sheet the background screen (i.e the home screen) is scrolled and there's no response inside the bottom sheet.
Here's a video demonstrating the issue:
[Scroll Issue](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iPN-wsqH4P4rB23jqWDr1NSQEvzSkeeY/view?usp=sharing)

Below is the code for your reference:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, FlatList, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import BottomSheet from 'react-native-simple-bottom-sheet';
import { LayoutAnimation } from 'react-native';
import { fontFamily } from '../../../assets/styles/FontStyle';
import DownArrowIcon from "../../../assets/img/icons/bottom_sheet_down_arrow.svg";
import UpArrowIcon from "../../../assets/img/icons/bottom_sheet_up_arrow.svg";
import RightArrowIcon from "../../../assets/img/icons/bottom_sheet_right_arrow.svg";
import CloseIcon from "../../../assets/img/icons/bottom_sheet_close_icon.svg";

type SpaceBottomSheetProps = {
    onClose: () => void;
}

const SpaceBottomSheet = ({ onClose }: SpaceBottomSheetProps) => {
    const bottomSheetRef = useRef<{ togglePanel: () => void; } | null>(); /*it seems like there's no @types entry for react-native-simple-bottom-sheet, could've just passed the type like this: useRef<BottomSheetType | null>(). That way we tell Typescript that either null (default value) or BottomSheetType (a type we currently can't import from anywhere, but can construct the type ourselves) will be the value in bottomSheetRef.current if .current is not null. */
    const [expandedItem, setExpandedItem] = useState(null);
    const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('screen').height;
    const bottomSheetHeight = screenHeight * 0.85;

    const closeBottomSheet = () => {
        if (bottomSheetRef.current) {
            bottomSheetRef.current.togglePanel();
            onClose(); // Call the onClose function when the bottom sheet is closed
        }
    };

    const data = [
        { label: '2D Test' },
        { label: '2D Testing 2' },
        { label: '2D Testing 3' },
        { label: '2D Testing 1' },
        { label: '2D Testzaffar' },
        { label: '2D TestZaffar' },
    ];

    const expandedData = [
        { label: 'Dashboard' },
        { label: 'List of Subspaces' },
        { label: 'View Space Details' },
        { label: 'Create Subspace' },
    ];

    const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
        const isExpanded = expandedItem === index;

        const handlePress = () => {
            LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut);
            setExpandedItem(isExpanded ? null : index);
        };

        return (
            <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={handlePress}>
                    <View style={styles.labelContainer}>
                        <Text style={styles.label}>{item.label}</Text>
                        {isExpanded ? (
                            <UpArrowIcon width={12} height={10} style={styles.arrowIcon} />
                        ) : (
                            <DownArrowIcon width={12} height={10} style={styles.arrowIcon} />
                        )}
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                {isExpanded && (
                    <FlatList
                        data={expandedData}
                        renderItem={({ item }) => (
                            <>
                                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.rowContainer}>
                                    <View style={styles.row}>
                                        <Text style={styles.rowLabel}>{item.label}</Text>
                                        <RightArrowIcon style={styles.rowArrowIcon} />
                                    </View>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                {item.label === 'List of Subspaces' && <View style={styles.separator} />}
                            </>
                        )}
                        keyExtractor={(item) => item.label}
                    />
                )}
            </View>
        );
    };
    //console.log('bottomSheetHeight:', bottomSheetHeight);
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <BottomSheet ref={bottomSheetRef} sliderMaxHeight={bottomSheetHeight} sliderMinHeight={0}>
                <View style={styles.bottomSheet}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => closeBottomSheet()} style={styles.closeIcon}>
                        <CloseIcon width={14.65} height={14.65} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <View style={styles.header}>
                        <Text style={styles.title}>Truminds</Text>
                        <Text style={[styles.create, { color: expandedItem !== null ? '#0F8D48' : '#4D4D4D' }]}>
                            + Create Subspace
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.separator} />
                    <FlatList
                        style={styles.list}
                        data={data}
                        renderItem={renderItem}
                        keyExtractor={(item) => item.label}
                    />
                </View>
            </BottomSheet>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
    },
    header: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        paddingHorizontal: 0,
        paddingTop: 28,
        paddingBottom: 12,
    },
    itemContainer: {
        backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',
        padding: 10,
        borderRadius: 10,
        marginBottom: 17,
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 24,
        fontWeight: '800',
        color: '#4D4D4D',
        fontFamily: fontFamily.theme.EXTRA_BOLD
    },
    create: {
        fontSize: 12,
        fontWeight: '600',
    },
    bottomSheet: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
        borderTopRightRadius: 20,
        paddingHorizontal: 5,
        paddingBottom: 10,
        marginTop: -20,
    },
    separator: {
        height: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#ddd',
        marginVertical: 10,
    },
    list: {
        marginTop: 10,
    },
    listItem: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        paddingVertical: 10,
    },
    labelContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        paddingBottom: 3,
        paddingTop: 3,
    },
    label: {
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: '600',
        color: '#4D4D4D',
    },
    arrowIcon: {
        marginLeft: 10,
        color: '#000000',
    },
    closeIcon: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'flex-end',
    },
    rowContainer: {
        paddingHorizontal: 4,
        paddingVertical: 10,
    },
    row: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
    },
    rowLabel: {
        fontSize: 12,
        fontWeight: '500',
        color: '#4D4D4D',
    },
    rowArrowIcon: {
        marginLeft: 10,
        color: '#000000',
    },
});

export default SpaceBottomSheet;
```

I tried wrapping it around the ScrollView but it's not working. Any help will be appreciated.